# Figure out which git commit a directory is from?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a git repository (let's call it `MyRepo`), a local working clone of the git repository, and a copy of a subdirectory of the main git repository from some other machine (let's call it `SomeSubDirectory`).

My git repository has a bit of history (~500 commits or so), and also a few branches.

Unfortunately, when originally copying `SomeSubDirectory` to another location, I forgot to note down which git commit hash it was from! How can I figure out which git commit hash this copy of `SomeSubDirectory` is from?

Comment: If the files are *all* the files from that directory, and has not been modified, try making a git repository for it, commit all the files and check the hash of the tree object, then see if that hash exists in the source repository.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `SomeSubDirectory` exists exactly, with all it's files, in some commit in my repository. Sadly though, it's not the only directory in the repository, so won't the commit hash be different?

In addition, `SomeSubDirectory` has been around a while and has changed a lot over time, so I'm after the commit at which `SomeSubDirectory` can be found exactly.

Comment: The commit hash, yes, but not the tree hash. The tree hash is calculated based on which files are present and their hashes, not when you committed or who you commit as, nor which parents existed for this commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), and by specifying the directory path, it will filter out the commits regarding that sub directory only:

```
git log --oneline SomeSubDirectory
```

Note: I've used the --oneline for a simpler output, but you can use any format you like.

This comes back with a list of commits ordered from most recent at the top, to the first commit at the bottom. Now, for simplicity, you could pipe this to [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) and get the last line - i.e. the first commit:

```
git log --oneline SomeSubDirectory | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I'm after the specific commit that has a version of `SomeSubDirectory` that's identical to a copy that's outside version control, not a list of commits in which it was changed, as `SomeSubDirectory` has rather a lot of history on it's own.

Comment: Now I get it, ok.